# How to write a long equation and number it?

Tags: equations, tags

I have the formula block:

```
 \begin{eqnarray} \tag{A8}  
  2x+3y+4z+2u+7o+8k+90l+43+56+45p+33h \nonumber \\
  &+& 89n+90m+34j+23a+45b+56f = 0
 \end{eqnarray}
```

but I am not getting the required equation with name `A8`. If anyone can figure it out you're most welcome.

Comment: `eqnarray` doesn't accept `\tag`. Only use `amsmath` environments and *never* `eqnarray`.

Answer (score 4):

You get

```
! Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
```

Only use `amsmath` environments to split equations across lines or to align them. *Never* use `eqnarray`. In this case, `multline` is the appropriate one.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
2x+3y+4z+2u+7o+8k+90l+43+56+45p+33h \\
+ 89n+90m+34j+23a+45b+56f = 0
\tag{A8}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the tag `\nonumber`, then the equation number doesn't print, please remove that command in your tag and then try, the modified tag is:

```
\begin{eqnarray} 
\tag{A8}  
 2x+3y+4z+2u+7o+8k+90l+43+56+45p+33h \\
&+& 89n+90m+34j+23a+45b+56f = 0\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
```

Also, note that `eqnarray` is one of the older environment, please try with `align` environment which comes along with `amsmath` package....

Corrected tag is:

```
 \begin{align} 
    \tag{A8}  
     &2x+3y+4z+2u+7o+8k+90l+43+56+45p+33h \\
    &\quad + 89n+90m+34j+23a+45b+56f = 0\nonumber
    \end{align}
```

Comment: The `multline` environment is also an option here.

Comment: @GuM Thanks for your notification...

Comment: Unfortunately (for you), egreg has been swifter in catching my hint!  (Hi, @egreg! ;-)

Comment: @GuM Ha ha ha, `egreg` is one of a legend in TeX....